# What is the best way to convert the jQuery .each() method to a native JavaScript abstraction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Hi and thanks for looking!

### Background

I am building my first application in Node.JS and am replacing jQuery-based habits with native JavaScript.

For most items, this is trivial; however, I am finding that I really miss the elegance of jQuery's `$.each()` abstraction and I would like to do something similar without relying on jQuery.

Unfortunately, the same code in JavaScript is a bit cumbersome:

```
myArray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = "Do Something Here".
};
```

What I would like to do is have something like this:

```
myArray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
myArray.each(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

### Question

Is there already an extension method out there for accomplishing this?  I can't help but think I am re-inventing the wheel.  If there isn't anything out there, would an extension method be best?

Comment: There's a `.forEach()` function on the native Array prototype.

Comment: what's wrong with a for loop? (other than your implicit global `i`)

Comment: For arrays: `arr.forEach( fn );`. For (non-array) objects: `Object.keys( obj ).forEach( fn );`.

Comment: @jbabey--Nothing per se, I just like to abstract things when I can do so without losing performance.  It's just personal preference; to me the code becomes more readable.

Comment: there is also `for( i in myArray ){ alert( i + ': ' + myArray[i] ); }`

Comment: @AlexanderV.B. Using `for...in` for arrays is a bad idea because it can pick up other random object properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forEach() in EcmaScript 5 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

But it's not comptatible with IE < 8.

So you may need to use this lib to be supported by all browsers : https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: Ok, thanks all!  I can't accept this answer for another 10 minutes. . .

Comment: @Pointy--Excuse my ignorance, but does the fact that I am in Node.js make this answer incorrect (I am seriously asking, not being a smart a$$).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt It means that you don't have to worry about IE :)

Answer (score 0):

ECMA Script 5 incorporates a method of Array called [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Usage is the same as `jQuery.each` for Arrays.

There is no need to use a `for...in` loop anymore, as `Array.forEach` is easily implemented (see the MDN Documentation link, middle of the document).

To clarify, `forEach` will loop through arrays only, not objects nor jQuery objects.

Comment: No, that's not quite true - the arguments passed to the callback are different between `$.each()` and the native `.forEach()`.

Comment: except that it's only a method of arrays, which makes it completely different than `jQuery.each`

Comment: I meant to say that usage is the same for Arrays only. 2 downvotes really necessary?

Comment: @Austin I didn't downvote but the usage really isn't the same - `.forEach()` passes `(value, index, array)` to the callback, while `$.each()` passes `(index, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
for( i in myArray ){ 
    alert( i + ': ' + myArray[i] ); /* your actions here */
}
```

Comment: You would also want to check `myArray.hasOwnProperty(i)` inside of your for loop... But this necessitates much more code than using Array.forEach

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `for ... in` on arrays.

Comment: @Pointy, even when you know what array you're dealing with? :)

Comment: @AlexanderV.B. yes - you're not even guaranteed to get the elements in numeric-index order.

Comment: @Pointy, where can I find more documentation about that. so far I found only [here - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) and [here - Associative Arrays chapter](http://www.openjs.com/articles/for_loop.php). Nothing bag about this method. And, so far, worked perfectly for me.

Comment: [Be careful with w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)  The other article is pretty bad too - JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays". It may work now, but the spec does not stipulate any order to the iteration in a `for ... in` loop. It's for iterating over properties of an object, which have no inherent ordering anyway.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is also available for node incase you'd want to stick to your habit.

```
npm install jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the async library if your objective is to use the foreach in node.js.  This allows you to parallelize your foreaches.

https://github.com/caolan/async